# Why are my tests failing and console.log() statements within a lodash method not logging?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, lodash

I have some failing tests that are breaking at various lodash methods but work fine in the browser.  While trying to debug I threw in some `console.log()`s within the callback argument to see what's going on, but they are not showing up in tests.  The same code run in the browser both works fine and writes to the console.  I suspect the breaking functionality is related to the missing log statements.

This is an Angular app in which I'm supplying lodash as a service.

**app**

```
app.value('_', window._);

app.service('myService', function(_) {
  return {
    filterNulls: function(obj) {
      // This logs correctly everywhere
      console.log(obj);

      return _.omit(obj, function(val, key) {
        // This logs in browsers but not in the Jasmine/Karma environment
        console.log('test');
        return val === null;
      });
    }    
  };
});
```

**tests**

```
describe('myService', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('_', window._);
    });
  });

  it('should strip nulls', inject(function(myService) {
    // FAILS because null value is not removed
    expect(myService.filterNulls({ 
        key: 'key1', 
        someProp: 'bar', 
        someOtherProp: null 
      }))
      .toEqual({ 
        key: 'key1', 
        someProp: 'bar'
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is lodash included for loading in your karma conf file?

Comment: Also, from the test, you're calling `stripNulls` while in the service there is only a function named `filterNulls`, which returns three values, not two, given the arguments you pass from the test.

Comment: Yes Lodash is included and that is a typo from copying code here for brevity.  I tried to be clear that the test is failing because of the null values not being stripped.  There are no reference errors, undefined functions, etc.  I assure you the setup and syntax are correct.

Comment: Sorry, it was late and I missed what you were getting at.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of why your logs aren't showing when Karma runs - they do for me when I test your code. There may be another problem which is not obvious to you or me.

I can say that your usage of `_.omit` is incorrect. From [the docs](http://lodash.com/docs#omit):

> The callback is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments;
>   (value, key, object).

Meanwhile, your callback parameters look like this:

```
function(key, val) { .. }
```

This minor adjustment makes your test pass for me:

```
function(val) { .. }
```

Comment: I have a syntax error in the code I copied, sorry.  In my actual code I have the `key, val` arguments correct.  I see you've edited your post a few times so this comment may be obsolete now but this works fine if you run it in the browser, so I don't think it's my understanding of the `omit` function: `_.omit({ foo: 'key1', bar: null }, function(val, key, obj) { return val === null; });` It must to be something to do with how I'm running lodash.  Thank you for your answer (and test results you posted previously).

Comment: My first answer was hackish - I didn't look into the callback signature - just adjusted the variables to make it work. Feeling that this was too lazy, I went to the docs and did it right the second time around. Sorry that I couldn't help you with the problem. I'm just really digging into Angular testing, so I thought it worthwhile for both of us to see if I could assist.

Comment: Best way to learn!  I've solved the issue, I'll post in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was an incorrect lodash reference.  The `karma.config` file was referencing a different version (`lodash.underscore.js`) than the application (`lodash.compat.js`).  A simple problem of collaborative development inconsistencies.

Comment: I was actually going to ask if somehow you'd loaded Underscore instead of lodash! ... since Underscore's `_.omit` doesn't accept a callback, which would explain why you aren't seeing the logs when running the tests. Glad you got to the bottom of it.